# ¿Cómo optimizar una lista de eventos?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Tengo el siguiente código.
Lo que hago es llamar a todos los elementos que tienen la clase 'btn', y los almaceno dentro de una variable 'btns', y se guardan en forma de array.

Luego a cada elemento que tengo le agrego un `.addEventListener` de tipo clic, el cual envía un formulario mediante `document.nombre_formulario.submit()`

```js
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

btns[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b0.submit()
});
btns[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b1.submit()
});
btns[2].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b2.submit()
});
btns[3].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b3.submit()
});
btns[4].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b4.submit()
});
btns[5].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b5.submit()
});
btns[6].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b7.submit()
});
btns[7].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b7.submit()
});
btns[8].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.b8.submit()
});
```

```css
.st1{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.st0{fill:none;}.st1{fill:#01133D;}.st2{font-weight: 600;}.st3{font-size:45px;}

.none{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="none">
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b0">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 0">
  </form>
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b1">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 1">
  </form>
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b2">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 2">
  </form>
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b3">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 3">
  </form>
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b4">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 4">
  </form>
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b5">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 5">
  </form>
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b6">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 6">
  </form>
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b7">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 7">
  </form>
  <form action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post" name="b8">
    <input type="hidden" name="bloque" value="Bloque 8">
  </form>
</div>

<svg id="Capa_2" data-name="Capa 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3194 1704">
  <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;}.cls-2{fill:#01133d;}</style></defs>
  <rect class="st0" width="3212" height="1704"/>
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1 bq" cx="924" cy="245" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 650.947 261.9419)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 0</text>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2088" cy="340" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2110.0256 444.7575)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 1</text>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2462" cy="340" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2543.1963 352.9999)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st2 st3">Bloque 2</tspan></text>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2629" cy="737" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2715.6465 751.45)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 3</text>
  </a> 
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2224.5" cy="815" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(0.8746 0.4848 -0.4848 0.8746 2130.384 877.3813)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st2 st3">Bloque 4</tspan>></text>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="1930" cy="689" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1850.0803 784.5)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 5</text>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2088" cy="1374" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2010.3236 1482.0002)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 6</text>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="1109" cy="1469" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1180.0188 1491.4501)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 7</text>
  </a>  
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="475" cy="1421" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 397.6863 1534.4501)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 8</text>
  </a>  
</svg>
```

Como se observa, tanto el índice del elemento que llamo en el array `btns[0]` y el nombre del formulario `b0` cuentan con el mismo número, pero siento que es un proceso muy repetitivo y quiero ver si hay la forma de automatizar ese proceso.

Nota: Estoy trabajando con Flask (python) para el backend y envío dichos datos por post.
No encontré otra forma de hacer que se envíen los datos al hacer clic en cierto elemento dentro de un svg que no fuera mediante `<a href="#"> </a>`, por eso la función de `document.nombre_formulario.submit()` en JavaScript.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el html de esos elementos?  Pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para modificarla las veces que creas necesario, gracias.

Comment: como Tenes el `array` con objetos adentro o solo un simple array? ejemplo: `array = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Ya incluí el html para que se pueda entender lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 0):

No se de Flask pero supongo que es algo asi lo que buscas hacer

```
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
   var nombreForm = 'b' + i;
   btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.nombreForm.Submit();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduciendo todo tu código yo haría estos cambios:

1. Quitaria **todos** los formularios dejando solo uno, pues si te fijas todos son muy semejantes y con el mismo *action* y el mismo *name* en el input, y lo único significativo que cambia es el value del input
2. Este uno lo pondría así:

```html
<form id="elformulario" action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post">
    <input id="bloque" type="hidden" name="bloque" value="">
</form>
```

donde se ha agregado un `id="elformulario"` para poder llamarlo desde javascript cómodamente e identificándolo de forma única, y se ha suprimido el **name** de la etiqueta  pues en esta solución no lo vamos a usar.

Fijarse que también se ha agregado un **id** al input, para también identificarlo después en el javascript de forma única.

3. En el javascript, tanto addEventListener() no parece demasiado óptimo, y lo he reducido al siguiente código:

```
// ponemos la escucha en el padre de todos los enlaces
Capa_2.addEventListener('click', function(event){

  // localizamos el elemento a padre del elemento clicado
  let a_padre_clicado = event.target.closest("a")

  // asignamos al input con id bloque su value
  bloque.value = "Bloque "+ ([...Capa_2.children].indexOf(a_padre_clicado)-2).toString()
  
  // enviamos el formulario
  elformulario.submit()
});
```

## Explicación ampliada del javascript

En esta línea:

```javascript
Capa_2.addEventListener('click', function(event){
```

- **Capa_2**: es el id que apunta al elemento padre que contiene los enlaces `<a>`
- Ponemos ese código para tan solo escuchar al elemento padre (**Capa_2**), con [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), el cual, dada la [delegación de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation), también recibe **todos** los eventos de sus hijos, a los cuales podemos identificar con la propiedad [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```
a_padre_clicado = event.target.closest("a")
```

Así pues, si sabemos que `event.target` se corresponde con el elemento clicado, y conociendo la estructura del contenido de los elementos **a**, vemos que sólo pueden ser hijos de dicho elemento, y se corresponderán o bien con un elemento `<circle>` o bien `<text>` en este caso concreto.

Siendo así, ahora queremos saber cual es el padre del elemento clicado, y lo buscamos con el método [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), el cual busca la primera coincidencia entre los ancestros del elemento event.target en este caso.

Y todo esto lo asignamos a una variable que denominamos `a_padre_clicado`, pues tal como su nombre pretende indicar, se corresponde con el elemento **a** padre que contiene el elemento hijo clicado (identificado con *event.target*).

Luego viene esta otra línea un poco más compleja:

```
bloque.value = "Bloque "+ ([...Capa_2.children].indexOf(a_padre_clicado)-2).toString()
```

con la que pretendemos asignar al *input* con el id **bloque** un valor, que estará compuesto de la palabra `"Bloque "` a la cual le concatenamos el índice del elemento `a_padre_clicado`, el cual lo buscamos de este modo:

```
([...Capa_2.children].indexOf(a_padre_clicado)-2)
```

donde:

- **[...Capa_2.children]**: representa un array generado mediante la [sintaxis de desestructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) y que cada elemento del array va a ser uno de los elementos hijos del elemento padre **Capa_2**, gracias a la propiedad [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children).
- **indexOf(a_padre_clicado)**: localiza el número de índice del elemento `a_padre_clicado` dentro de ese array anterior, gracias al método [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- **-2**:  es un número que vamos a restar a dicho íncide del elemento `a_padre_clicado` encontrado en las instrucciones anteriores. ¿Y porque? Pues porque el padre de `a_padre_clicado` no solo contiene como hijos los elementos `<a>`, sino que empieza con dos distintos, a saber:

```
<defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;}.cls-2{fill:#01133d;}</style></defs>
<rect class="st0" width="3212" height="1704"/>
```

y luego sí, el resto son elementos `<a>` consecutivos, por lo tanto debemos restarlos para saber el número de orden del elemento `<a>` clicado real, sin contar con esos otros dos.

Y para asegurarnos que la concatenación entre strings va a ser correcta, pasamos el resultado de las instrucciones anteriores a string mediante el método [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

Por lo tanto, como decía, esta línea consigue asignar al input con id bloque el value esperado:

```
bloque.value = "Bloque "+ ([...Capa_2.children].indexOf(a_padre_clicado)-2).toString()
```

el cual será "Bloque x", donde la **x** representa el índice de `<a>` tal como acabo de explicar.

Por último, como ya tenemos el valor puesto en el input en la instrucción anterior, ya podemos enviar el formulario de este modo:

```
  elformulario.submit()
```

Ya nos dirás si lo has entendido y te ha funcionado (y si has leído tenido la paciencia de leerlo todo hasta aquí, jeje)

Aquí dejo un snippet completo (que aquí no parece hacer nada, pero [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/avzenktL/) se puede apreciar mejor que lo intenta a pesar del error 404 porque no existe el script del action):

```js
// ponemos la escucha en el padre de todos los enlaces
Capa_2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  // localizamos el elemento a padre del elemento clicado
  el_a = event.target.closest("a")

  // asignamos al input con id bloque su value
  bloque.value = "Bloque " + ([...Capa_2.children].indexOf(el_a) - 2).toString()

  // enviamos el formulario
  elformulario.submit()
});
```

```css
st1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
}

.st1 {
  fill: #01133D;
}

.st2 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.st3 {
  font-size: 45px;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="none">
  <form id="elformulario" action="/reportar-daño/genre" method="post">
    <input id="bloque" type="hidden" name="bloque" value="">
  </form>
</div>

<svg id="Capa_2" data-name="Capa 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3194 1704">
  <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;}.cls-2{fill:#01133d;}</style></defs>
  <rect class="st0" width="3212" height="1704"/>
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1 bq" cx="924" cy="245" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 650.947 261.9419)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 0</text>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2088" cy="340" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2110.0256 444.7575)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 1</text>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2462" cy="340" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2543.1963 352.9999)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st2 st3">Bloque 2</tspan></text>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2629" cy="737" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2715.6465 751.45)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 3</text>
  </a> 
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2224.5" cy="815" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(0.8746 0.4848 -0.4848 0.8746 2130.384 877.3813)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st2 st3">Bloque 4</tspan>></text>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="1930" cy="689" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1850.0803 784.5)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 5</text>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="2088" cy="1374" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2010.3236 1482.0002)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 6</text>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="1109" cy="1469" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1180.0188 1491.4501)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 7</text>
  </a>  
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">
    <circle class="st1" cx="475" cy="1421" r="47.5"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 397.6863 1534.4501)" class="st2 st3">Bloque 8</text>
  </a>  
</svg>
```